# Why CSS3 perspective is not working in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, transform

I am trying to create a 3d flipcard . But perspective property is not working in firefox v21 .

see the code http://codepen.io/prantor19/pen/cgoKm

can you explain why?

Comment: You need to paste the code here, not just the link, if link will be dead, this question will be useless for future visitors

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you forgot px after perspective value!!

like this:

```
  -webkit-perspective:600px;
  -moz-perspective:600px;
  perspective:600px;
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
-webkit-perspective:600;

-webkit-perspective:600px;

perspective:600px;
```

'perspective:600px;' is ok in chrome,but 'perspective:600;' has wrong with it.