# CSS3 effects doesn't work

Tags: css, mozilla, flip

If I try to make an only css3 flip effect and that will work in all major browsers, I fail.

anaxshipping.com/site is the url and the flipping effect is at home page at the three top icons.

```
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -ms-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;

-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
```

I tried also the perspective with px. In chrome it works. In Mozilla it doesn't. Should I paste the rest of the code?

```
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  -ms-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

/* flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {

  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-container, .front, .back {
//  width: 100%;
//  height: 21em;
  width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {

  -webkit-transition:0.6s;
  -moz-transition:0.6s;
  -ms-transition:0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {

  z-index: 2;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Firefox 30 - works fine.

Comment: I have also the latest Firefox I cleared the browser cache...so why am I seeing a "bug" in the flipping effect?

Comment: Yes, paste the rest of your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bug with CSS -moz-perspective](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775127/bug-with-css-moz-perspective)

Comment: What sort of bug? it looks great.

Comment: Another possible duplicate of [Why CSS3 perspective is not working in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751007/why-css3-perspective-is-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: I don't know guys..One time I fixed it with adding "px" later it broke again. 


.flip-container, .front, .back {
  width: 320px;height: 480px;
}


.flipper {


-webkit-transition:0.6s;
-moz-transition:0.6s;
-ms-transition:0.6s;
transition: 0.6s;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style:preserve-3d;position: relative;
}


.front, .back {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}

Comment: Working fine in Chrome 35

Comment: In Chrome yes it works fine but I don't get the same result in Mozilla (latest).

Answer (score 0):

for 3D animations, use this ordering:
(for better realization i wrote it in nested form)

```
#world {
    perspective: 1000px; //px needed
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000px; //px needed

    #container {
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

        .elements {
            transform: ... ;
            -webkit-transform: ... ;
            -moz-transform: ... ;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> .flip-container, .front, .back {
>
> -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
>   }

I have added there the preserve-3d for Mozilla and it worked.

Thank you for the feedback!